# isinstance in composition cant compare values in if

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

I trying to use isinstance but i get the false return and not the true. My code is below:

```
from CD import CD
from DVD import DVD

class Catalogo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__itens = list()
        self.cd = CD("ti", "te", "ar"," nu", "po", "co")
        self.dvd = DVD("ti", "di", "te", "po", "co")

    def appendItem(self, item):
        self.__itens.append(item)

    def listarItem(self):
        print("CDs\n")
        for i in self.__itens:           
            if isinstance(i, CD):
                print(i,'\n')           
            else:
                print(i + " is not here.")
        print("DVDs\n")
        for i in self.__itens:
            if isinstance(i,DVD):
                print(i,'\n')
#Another file
from catalogo import Catalogo
class main(object):


    ct = Catalogo()


    ct.appendItem(ct.cd.setArtista('Gilberto'))
    ct.appendItem(ct.cd.setArtista('Zeca'))      
    ct.appendItem(ct.dvd.setDiretor('Carlos'))
    ct.listarItem()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I tryed to change CD and DVD by others values but teh code dont let me. My question is how can i compare i and self.__itens in the for? my class CD, DVD, Catalago and main are in diferent files, i dont put then here cause they just have a constroct. Thnx guys!!

Comment: As far as I understand your `appendItem` (which you have not shown in class) appends the return value of function `ct.cd.setArtista('Gilberto')` and not the `CD` class instance. What you can do is check the type of type of items in list by `for i in self.__itens:print(type(i))`

Comment: I added the add function. I tried teste i typpe before and it return str, and for the self.__itens it return list type.And i dont know what else can i do to it work!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just answer that.

```
from CD import CD
from DVD import DVD

class Catalogo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__itens = list()


    def appendItem(self, item):
        self.__itens.append(item)

    def listarItem(self):
        print("CDs\n")
        for i in self.__itens:           
            if isinstance(i, CD):
                print(i,'\n')           
            else:
                print(i + " is not here.")
        print("DVDs\n")
        for i in self.__itens:
            if isinstance(i,DVD):
                print(i,'\n')
#Another file
from catalogo import Catalogo
class main(object):


    ct = Catalogo()

    cd = CD("ti ", "te", "ar"," nu", "po", "co")

    ct.appendItem(cd)

    ct.listarItem()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I just make some mistakes but i fix that, follow the differences.